# Combine two function_score queries in dis_max

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to make a query with two subqueries, each of them has it's own scoring based on function_score with script. For example, this subquery:

```
 {
   "query":{
      "function_score":{
         "query":{
            "bool":{
               "filter":[
                  {
                     "term":{
                        "rooms_count":3
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "term":{
                        "addresses":"d76255c8-3173-4db5-a39b-badd3ebdf851"
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "exists":{
                        "field":"zhk_id"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         "script_score":{
            "script":"1 * doc['price'].value/100000"
         },
         "boost_mode":"replace"
      }
   }
    }
```

works fine, and it's score is based on price (about 190 points). But if I try to combine two subqueries in dis_max query, function_score is not working and I get scores about 1 point.

Explanation for each subquery looks like this

```
    "value": 100.9416, "description": "script score function, computed with script:"[script: 1 * doc['price'].value/100000, type: inline, lang: null, params: {}]" and parameters:
{}",
```

for dis_max query like

```
 "value": 1, "description": "ConstantScore(function score (#rooms_count: #addresses:d76255c8-3173-4db5-a39b-badd3ebdf851 #ConstantScore(fieldnames:zhk_id),function=script[script: 1 * doc['price'].value/100000, type: inline, lang: null, params: {}])), product of:",`
```

Can anybody tell me, how to combine function_score queries properly?

My full dis_max query [on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/CfFu6XgA)

Comment: can share how you are combining the two sub queries along with your schema mappings

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Daniel Mitterdorfer from https://discuss.elastic.co/t/combine-two-function-score-queries-in-dis-max/70666.

correct query is

```
 {
   "query":{
      "dis_max":{
         "queries":[
        {
                        "function_score":{
                           "query":{
                              "bool":{
                                 "filter":[
                                    {
                                       "term":{
                                          "rooms_count":3
                                       }
                                    },
                                    {
                                       "term":{
                                          "addresses":"d76255c8-3173-4db5-a39b-badd3ebdf851"
                                       }
                                    },
                                    {
                                       "missing":{
                                          "field":"zhk_id"
                                       }
                                    }
                                 ]
                              }
                           },
                           "script_score":{
                              "script":"1 * doc['price'].value/100000"
                           },
                           "boost_mode":"replace"
                        }
                  },
        {
                        "function_score":{
                           "query":{
                              "bool":{
                                 "filter":[
                                    {
                                       "term":{
                                          "rooms_count":3
                                       }
                                    },
                                    {
                                       "term":{
                                          "addresses":"d76255c8-3173-4db5-a39b-badd3ebdf851"
                                       }
                                    },
                                    {
                                       "exists":{
                                          "field":"zhk_id"
                                       }
                                    }
                                 ]
                              }
                           },
                           "script_score":{
                              "script":"1 * doc['price'].value/100000"
                           },
                           "boost_mode":"replace"
                        }
                     }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```